# MySQL Searching and Joining a Superset of Tags

Tags: mysql, join, tags

I am trying to create a query which, for the sake of simplicity, searches a set of tags associated with a set of blog posts and returns:

1) The blog posts with tags which match the search query
AND
2) Any additional tags associated with that blog post, not necessarily matching the search term.

The blog posts are stored in one table:

```
table: entries
id  | entry
------------- 
1   | entry 1
2   | entry 2
3   | entry 3
...
```

and the tags are stored in another table.

```
table: tags
id | entry_id | tag
---------------------------
1  | 1        | tag_1
2  | 1        | another
3  | 2        | another_tag
4  | 3        | third_entry        
....
```

The MySQL query is structured as follows:

```
SELECT entries.entry, tags.tag FROM entries 
LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.entry_id = entries.id where tags.tag like '%tag%'
```

This returns:

```
entry     |    tag
--------------------
entry 1   |   tag_1
entry 2   |   another_tag
```

So, the query correctly searches for the tag, but I want to pull any additional tags associated with those two entries as I'm going to display the superset of the tags in the search results. Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: So you want all tags from the posts that have tag_1 and another_tag?

Comment: For any entries that came up as part of the search results, I now want to pull all tags for those entries.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong but your database design is wrong. You have to make a table entry_tag with entry_id tag_id to model the many to many relationship. Have you done that?

Comment: I haven't -- It was designed as a one-to-many relationship. If I change the design to many-to-many, how will that affect this query?

Comment: currently, it only accepts one tag per post.

Comment: Altered it to a many:many relationship, but I'm still only getting returned one tag per entry: 'select entries.entry, tags.tag from entries
left join entries_tags on entries_tags.entry_id = entries.id
left join tags on tags.id = entries_tags.tag_id
where tags.tag like '%tag%''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'select entries.entry, tags.tag from entries left join entries_tags on entries_tags.entry_id = entries.id left join tags on tags.id = entries_tags.tag_id where tags.tag like '%tag%''

SELECT entries.entry from (select entries.entry, tags.tag from entries left join entries_tags on entries_tags.entry_id = entries.id left join tags on tags.id = entries_tags.tag_id where tags.tag like '%tag%') natural join entries_tags

try that.

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful. I actually built a working query based partially on this... See new answer post for full details.

Answer (score 0):

Based on alfa64's guidance, I built out the following query which now properly pulls the searched tags and retrieves any additional tags for each respective blog post:

```
SELECT q1.id, q1.entry, q1.tag from (select entries.entry, tags.tag from entries 
LEFT JOIN entries_tags on entries_tags.entry_id = entries.id 
LEFT JOIN tags on tags.id = entries_tags.tag_id where tags.tag like '%tag%') as q1 
JOIN entries_tags as et1 on et1.entry_id =  q1.id
JOIN tags as t2 on t2.id = et1.tag_id
GROUP BY t2.id
```